# SQL Statistics IO and the Execution Plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In regards with SQL performance, in which aspects of the *Query Execution Plan* the *Statistics IO* can help to reveal potential performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete answer to this question would require an article to be written :)

To be concise, here are few tips..

Query Execution Plan:

1. It shows how the query is actually executed.
2. If you observe the execution plan closely, you will observe that the query logic is divided into different sections. If you see an arrow with more height, that means that particular join/predicate is returning many rows. You may need to do further filtering of rows there.
3. Sometimes, execution plan suggests you few indexes along with script to create those indexes which will help you in improving performance.
4. It details the predicates used in query and amount of rows it returns.
5. the percentage value you see in the execution plan is relative to the other parts of the script.

IO Statistics:

1. IO Statistics give you the execution time of different queries in your script in terms of CPU usage and disk usage.
2. You can go through the execution plan and identify which part of your script is taking maximum time.
3. Make sure you turn off IO statistic once you are done with analysis. It will add overhead to the server.

Hope it explains to some extent!

Comment: Thanks for that. It gives me a a good point for the IO Statistics usage.

Comment: Glad that i could help you! :)